# Disappearing `+` in Django url regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I have created the following url in Django. My goal is to match and capture an integer of any length as `bd`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^load/(?P<bd>[0-9]+)/$', views.home, name='home_with_load')
]
```

This urls.py is being included by the main urls.py with a namespace like this:

```
url(r'^mission-control/', include('mission_control.urls', namespace='mission-control'))
```

When I go to http://localhost/mission-control/load/5 (a single digit number integer), I am taken to the expected view. However, when I go to the url http://localhost/mission-control/load/54 (a two-digit integer), I am brought to the django error debug page, which shows that I failed to match this pattern:

```
^mission-control/ ^load/(?P<bd>[0-9])/$ [name='home_with_load']
```

Note that the `+` that should follow the `[0-9]` has disappeared. That explains why my two-digit integer is failing to match.

Why did the `+` disappear? Is there some error in my regex that makes the `+` meaningless so that it it removed during regex compilation?

---

**Debug notes:**

- I get the same result when using `\d+`. It turns into just `\d`.
- I have made sure to kill and restart django to ensure my url regex is recompiled. I've made meaningless changes (like changing the name of `bd`) and confirmed that they take effect and show on the error debug page.
- I temporarily raised a `ValueError` in the mission-control url.py to confirm it is being read.

Comment: Django is definitly NOT "changing" anything from your regexp. Also the code snippet and error message do not match (in the second case, the captured part is named 'bd', not 'myvar').

Comment: Sorry, that was an error in sanitizing my question. Fixed now.

Comment: Well, Django STILL doesn't change your regexps so your problem is elsewhere. Is your urlpattern in the main url.py or is it included ? Is it possible that you have any stale url.pyc file ? (hint: clean up all .pyc files from your project directory). What happens if you add something like "raise ValueError('this is a test')" at the top of your urls.py file ? Does it crash or does your site still work ? If yes then you're not editing the righ urls.py file ;)

Comment: You have a version of that URL without the + around _somewhere_.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, thank you for the suggestions. I tried removing all .pyc files, and there was not change. I put `raise ValueError("this is a test") in the urls.py, and the error was indeed thrown.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, this urls.py is being included. I had trimmed that out to simplify my question, but since it seems relevant now, let me edit my question to include those details. One moment.

Comment: Do you go to `localhost/load/54` or `localhost/mission-control/load/54`?

Comment: @vd1, whoops, localhost/mission-control/load/54. Edited to fix.

Comment: What happens if you use `[0-9][0-9]*` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mission-control urls.py had this at the top

```
# -*- coding: utf-7 -*-
```

Changing that to

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

fixed the problem and my `+` started showing up.

Not sure what bootstrapper/cookiecutter/template/example I got the utf-7 from. My bad, folks.